# Python return list of items that fit set parameters

Tags: python, algorithm, iteration, scientific-computing

I'm having some difficulty properly boxing the returned solution to the min_cals <= sum(calories) <= max_cals. There are combinations that yield solutions where sum(cals) < min_cals. In addition to remaining within the caloric range the solution should yield a list where the sum(cost approaches as closely to budget as possible without exceeding the budget limit. Here's some re-contextualized code. I could really use a hand:

```
menu = [
    {'name':'Cheese Pizza Slice', 'calories': 700, 'cost': 4},
    {'name':'House Salad', 'calories': 100, 'cost': 8.5},
    {'name':'Grilled Shrimp', 'calories': 400, 'cost': 15},
    {'name':'Beef Brisket', 'calories': 400, 'cost': 12},
    {'name':'Soda', 'calories': 100, 'cost': 1},
    {'name':'Cake', 'calories': 300, 'cost': 3},
]

def menu_recommendation(menu, min_cal, max_cal, budget):
    menu = [item for item in menu if item['calories'] <= max_cal and item['cost'] <= budget]
    if len(menu) == 0: return []
    return min((
        [item] + menu_recommendation(menu, min_cal - item['calories'], max_cal - item['calories'], budget - item['cost'])
        for item in menu
    ), key= 
        lambda recommendations: [budget - sum(item['cost'] for item in recommendations) and min_cal <= sum(item['calories'] for item in recommendations) <= max_cal, -sum(item['calories'] for item in recommendations)]
    )

recommendation = menu_recommendation(menu, 1000, 1200, 15)
total_cost = sum(item['cost'] for item in recommendation)
total_cals = sum(item['calories'] for item in recommendation)
print(f'recommendation: {recommendation}')
print(f'total cost: {total_cost}')
print(f'total calories: {total_cals}')
```

for example, the following returns a solution with a total calorie count of 700, which is below the 1000 minimum.
recommendation = menu_recommendation(menu, 1000, 1200, 15)

Comment: use a genetic algorithm

Comment: You could use a genetic algorithm, but with a linear objective and linear constraints, you're probably better off with mixed integer programming: https://developers.google.com/optimization/mip/integer_opt#using-a-mip-solver

Comment: @DavidEisenstat thanks for pointing me at google OR-Tools. i didn't know about this resource, and I didn't know the language necessary to search for something like this. cheers :)

Comment: *I'm not sure*, but can't it be solved using a variant of [knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)? It computes a matrix `C[i,w]`, highest possible value using first `i` items that weighs less than `w`. Assume calorie as the weight, and budget as value. After `C` is computed, seek the cells where `min_cal <= w <= max_cal` to find highest value that is lower than budget.

Comment: to me it seems like a common knapsack problem, but with 2 constraints and the best way to solve is dynamic programming. I would guess that this is some exam/interview problem?
see here to learn more https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems
or more specifically here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems

Answer (score 1):

We can work up something recursive, probably.

```
def smallest_combo(lst, m, n, z):
    # filter list to remove elements we can't use next without breaking the rules
    lst = [dct for dct in lst if m <= dct['x'] <= n and dct['y'] <= z]
    # recursive base case
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    # go through our list of eligibles
    # simulate 'what would the best possibility be if we picked that one to go with next'
    # then of those results select the one with the sum('y') closest to z
    #   (breaking ties with the largest sum('x'))
    return min((
        [dct] + smallest_combo(lst, m - dct['x'], n - dct['x'], z - dct['y'])
        for dct in lst
    ), key= 
        lambda com: [z - sum(d['y'] for d in com), -sum(d['x'] for d in com)]
    )

inp = [{'name': 'item1', 'x': 600, 'y': 5},
 {'name': 'item2', 'x': 200, 'y': 8},
 {'name': 'item3', 'x': 500, 'y': 12.5},
 {'name': 'item4', 'x': 0, 'y': 1.5},
 {'name': 'item5', 'x': 100, 'y': 1}]
print(smallest_combo(inp, 500, 1500, 25))
# [{'name': 'item3', 'x': 500, 'y': 12.5}, {'name': 'item3', 'x': 500, 'y': 12.5}]
```

There would be a number of ways to speed this up. First by making a recursive cache, and second by taking a dynamic programming approach instead (i.e. start at the bottom instead of at the top).

Comment: this is really helpful, but I don't understand how the lambda function works. How does the second half of the expression evaluate, and why is the expression wrapped in brackets? I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here, and i'm having trouble finding what looks like an adequate analogy in the python docs.

Comment: @Yup. the lambda takes each combination (a list of dicts), and returns what's essentially a 2-tuple: `z` minus the sum of `'y'` for every dict therein, and the negative sum of `'x'` for each sum therein. The functions `sorted()`, `min()`, etc. can accept iterables as keys which tell them _how_ to sort, and compare elements in order of priority - elements beyond the first are used as a tiebreaker if elements before them are legal. I use square brackets to make it a list instead of a tuple for no reason besides making the expression slightly more clear.

Comment: i've updated the problem to add some clarity on an issue and i would very much appreciate your input.

Comment: I get `KeyError: 'x'` line 3 in `smallest_combo()` for the example from the question.

Comment: @greybeard Keep in mind this code was built to fit this particular example input, where every `dict` has the keys `'name'`, `'x'`, and `'y'`. You need to ensure that this is the case in your situation as well, or change what the variables are referring to, or add error handling.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dynamic programming solution that builds up a data structure showing all of the `(calorie, cost)` options we can wind up with along with one item each.  We look for the best one meeting the criteria, then find what recommendation that is.

```
def menu_recommendation(menu, min_cal, max_cal, budget):
    # This finds the best possible solution in pseudo-polynomial time.
    recommendation_tree = {(0, 0.0): None}
    for item in menu:
        # This tree will wind up being the old plus new entries from adding this item.
        new_recommendation_tree = {}
        for key in recommendation_tree.keys():
            calories, cost = key
            new_recommendation_tree[key] = recommendation_tree[key]
            new_key = (calories + item['calories'], cost + item['cost'])
            if new_key not in recommendation_tree and new_key[0] <= max_cal:
                # This is a new calorie/cost combination to look at.
                new_recommendation_tree[new_key] = item
        # And now save the work.
        recommendation_tree = new_recommendation_tree

    # Now we look for the best combination.
    best = None
    for key in recommendation_tree:
        calories, cost = key
        # By construction, we know that calories <= max_cal
        if min_cal <= calories:
            if best is None or abs(budget - cost) < abs(budget - best[1]):
                # We improved!
                best = key

    if best is None:
        return None
    else:
        # We need to follow the tree back to the root to find the recommendation
        calories, cost = best
        item = recommendation_tree[best]
        answer = []
        while item is not None:
            # This item is part of the menu.
            answer.append(item)
            # And now find where we were before adding this item.
            calories = calories - item['calories']
            cost = cost - item['cost']
            best = (calories, cost)
            item = recommendation_tree[best]
        return answer
```

Comment: this is an interesting approach, but i have encountered a bug when running this with the following scenario: 
recommendation = menu_recommendation(menu, 800, 1000, 4)
I expected to receive an empty list, indicating no possible solutions, but instead I got a recommendation with the following:
total cost: 5
total calories: 800
the total cost exceeds the available budget.

I adjusted the code as follows and seem to be back on track receiving a None:

if new_key not in recommendation_tree and new_key[0] <= max_cal and new_key[1] <= budget:

Comment: You said in your description that you wanted to be as close to the budget as possible.  If you just want to not exceed the budget, I can make finding the cheapest solution in the right calorie range much more efficient.

Comment: It won't always be cheapest, but it will be within budget.  And it will usually be cheap.

Comment: that sounds great, i would love to see your more efficient solution. Cheapest is not desirable for this. In fact the most desirable solution comes closest to budget without exceeding budget, while min_cal <= total_cal <= max_cal. I will update description to be more clear :)

Comment: @Yup. Efficient is simply to do an A* search for the cheapest path to the right calorie range.  But it will not work for your criteria as well as this does.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this, it's basically a knapsack but it removes recursively dishes from the menu if they are not suitable for the recommendation:

```
menu = [
    {'name':'Cheese Pizza Slice', 'calories': 700, 'cost': 4},
    {'name':'House Salad', 'calories': 100, 'cost': 8.5},
    {'name':'Grilled Shrimp', 'calories': 400, 'cost': 15},
    {'name':'Beef Brisket', 'calories': 400, 'cost': 12},
    {'name':'Soda', 'calories': 100, 'cost': 1},
    {'name':'Cake', 'calories': 300, 'cost': 3},
]



def get_price(recommendation):
    return sum(dish["cost"] for dish in recommendation)

def get_calories(recommendation):
    return sum(dish["calories"] for dish in recommendation)

def menu_recommendation(menu, min_cal, max_cal, budget):
    sorted_menu = sorted(menu, key=lambda dish: dish["cost"], reverse=True)
    recommendation = []
    for dish in sorted_menu:
      if dish["cost"] + get_price(recommendation) <= budget:
        recommendation.append(dish)
    if recommendation:
      if get_calories(recommendation) < min_cal:
        sorted_menu.remove(min(recommendation, key=lambda dish: dish["calories"]/dish["cost"]))
        return menu_recommendation(sorted_menu, min_cal, max_cal, budget)
      if get_calories(recommendation) > max_cal:
        sorted_menu.remove(max(recommendation, key=lambda dish: dish["calories"]/dish["cost"]))
        return menu_recommendation(sorted_menu, min_cal, max_cal, budget)
    return recommendation




recommendation = menu_recommendation(menu, 500, 800, 15)
total_cost = sum(item['cost'] for item in recommendation)
total_cals = sum(item['calories'] for item in recommendation)
print(f'recommendation: {recommendation}')
print(f'total cost: {total_cost}')
```

It removes elements according to the calorie/cost rate, because it's the cost to which is applied the knapsack.

Please let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved the issue of making recommendations that were outside of the scoped min_cal / max_cal boundaries, but I still feel like there could be a solution that more closely approaches budget.

Here is my updated code:

```
menu = [
    {'name':'Cheese Pizza Slice', 'calories': 700, 'cost': 4},
    {'name':'House Salad', 'calories': 100, 'cost': 8.5},
    {'name':'Grilled Shrimp', 'calories': 400, 'cost': 15},
    {'name':'Beef Brisket', 'calories': 400, 'cost': 12},
    {'name':'Soda', 'calories': 100, 'cost': 1},
    {'name':'Cake', 'calories': 300, 'cost': 3},
]

def menu_recommendation(menu, min_cal, max_cal, budget):
    menu = [item for item in menu if item['calories'] <= max_cal and item['cost'] <= budget]
    if len(menu) == 0: return []
    return min(([item] + menu_recommendation(menu, min_cal - item['calories'], max_cal - item['calories'], budget - item['cost']) 
        for item in menu
), key= 
    lambda recommendations: [budget - sum(item['cost'] for item in recommendations) 
                             and min_cal - sum(item['calories'] for item in recommendations) >= 0
                             and max_cal - sum(item['calories'] for item in recommendations) >= 0, 
                             -sum(item['calories'] for item in recommendations)]
)

recommendation = menu_recommendation(menu, 1000, 1200, 15)
total_cost = sum(item['cost'] for item in recommendation)
total_cals = sum(item['calories'] for item in recommendation)
print(f'recommendation: {recommendation}')
print(f'total cost: {total_cost}')
print(f'total calories: {total_cals}')
```

If anyone has any improvements I'd love to hear them!

Comment: 0/1 Knapsack can be used to find an optimal solution if the number of items or the budget isn't really large